# Animated.loop image

Tags: react-native, react-animated

Back in 1996 I created spinning logos for clients, because I could, and now in 2017 I'm back at it, thanks to [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html).

The code below the `<hr />` works, but there's a tiny bump when it restarts.

Any idea how I can use `Animated.loop`? It doesn't: «*each time it reaches the end, it resets and begins again from the start*».

```
Animated.loop(
  Animated.timing(this.state.spinValue, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: this.props.duration,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true
  })
).start();
```

---

```
static defaultProps = {
  duration: 60 / (33 + 1/3) * 1000
}

constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    spinValue: new Animated.Value(0)
  };
}

componentDidMount () {
  this._animate();
}

_animate () {
  Animated.timing(this.state.spinValue, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: this.props.duration,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true
  }).start(event => {
    if (event.finished) {
      this.setState({
        spinValue: new Animated.Value(0)
      }, this._animate.bind(this));
    }
  });
}

render () {
  const spin = this.state.spinValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
  });
  return (
    <View style={ Loading.style.container }>
      <Animated.Image
        source={ logo }
        style={{ transform: [{ rotate: spin }] }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to use react-native-LoopAnimation.js' 
https://github.com/Infinity0106/react-native-LoopAnimation

```
import LoopAnimation from 'react-native-LoopAnimation.js' 
...
render() {
  //you can also use, like source={imgSource}
  const imgSource=
  {uri:'http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg',width:700,height:306};

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      {/*this is the background animation */}
      <LoopAnimation source={require('./img/back.jpg')} duration={10000} />
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        {/*Content goes here*/}
        <View style={{width: 200, height: 400, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        </View>
    </View>
   );
  }
```

Comment: It seems that library is using `Animated.sequence`. I'd like to stick to pure React Native.

Comment: The above library has no licence information provided, so cannot realistically be used in a live application.